# How to change to helvetice font in class based on class option?

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I want to based on a class option change to using Helvetica as font, the simplest way I found to do this would be to load the `helvet` package. But if I do that like:

```
\DeclareOption{foo}{
    \RequirePackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
}
```

I get told that:

```
! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.
```

i.e., I am not allowed to load packages between \DeclareOption and \ProcessOptions. But that would mean that I can't load different packages based on option? How can I then do things like change font based on Options? In fact, most things I do in LaTeX I do by loading packages, how can I do anything much at all based on options in class files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading a package conditionally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/loading-a-package-conditionally) Unrelated: I'd replace `helvetica` by `tgheros` (much broader glyph coverage especially in `TS1` encoding).

Comment: Completely different way of asking but yea it's the same thing. Wow, writing class files really  makes you jump through hoops...